# Drupal: how to show the secondary links to non-authenticated users

Tags: drupal, administration

I have a secondary links bar at the top which seems to only display for authenticated users.

Does anyone know how I can change this for all visitors to see?

Answer (score 0):

It should, unless the pages it's linking to don't allow access to anonymous users.

Are you displaying it as a block or directly from $secondary_links on page.tpl.php?

Comment: ah ok, yeah the pages are all content creation pages which you need to be logged into to access but is there anyway to display the menu and just redirect to a log in page when they click an item. The menu gives a lot of information about what the site is all about so i'd like visitor to see it too

Comment: I've used this module in the past. http://drupal.org/project/premium it's pretty good, I had to edit the module a little bit so it didn't display the teaser. just a link for the users to sign up to view the content. Otherwise you'll get a no go with drupal's current access system.